# Connection timeout in dockerized metabase

Tags: docker, docker-network, metabase

I have two different services on one server up and running with docker.

One service contains metabase with following docker-compose file.

```
  metabase:
    container_name: metabase
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    ports:
      - "3102:3000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - metabase-data:/metabase
```

And another service contains mongo db:

```
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_PORT:-27017}:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
```

I tried `host.docker.internal` , my server public address, localhost etc but nothing works. and always receive connection timeout.

Netcat test is sucessfull from my local machine

```
nc -v 212.xx.xxx.175 27017
Connection to 212.xx.xxx.175 27017 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But tried these in metabase container and all of them ends up  with 'operation timed out'

```
nc -v host.docker.internal 27017
nc: host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1:0): Operation timed out
```

I also can access my database from mongo compass app, (so im pretty sure it's not about firewall) but no chance when using metabase.

Update:
Creating **bridge** network in one docker-compose and use it as **external** network in another, works. My main question is why it doesn't work with my public address or host.docker.internal?

Answer (score 0):

If both of the service exist in the same `docker-compose.yml` file then they can communicate via the Docker network using the service name as their DNS name.

```
version: "3"

services:
  metabase:
    container_name: metabase
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - metabase-data:/metabase
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:4.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${MONGODB_PORT:-27017}:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGODB_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
volumes:
  metabase-data:
  mongodb-data:
```

Now from within the running Metabase container you can do:

```
nc -v mongodb 27017
```

and it will open a connection to the MongoDB container on port 27017.

Screenshot below shows:

- LHS: `nc` connection to MongoDB container and
- RHS: Metabase configuration for connecting to MongoDB (open http://127.0.0.1:3000 in browser for Metabase).

You will probably need to sort out SSL for the connection to the database, but that is another matter!

[image]

Comment: it's a micro service app and I don't wanna do this. even if I share network between them. it doesn't work. it has problem accessing port exposed by docker.